# Jquery .removeClass before append fails on <tr>

Tags: jquery, append, attr, removeclass

see jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/codenoob/3v3mfndg/1/

I have a table  that is hidden. I set that as a template to clone more row.

however I want to remove the hidden class when appending new rows but cant.

It can removeClass on all the element after the `<tr>`

test it by removing the hidden class from `<tr>` and run the code.

what did I do wrong?

if you cant use jsfiddle here are the code

HTML

```
<table id="cloneinhere">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="clone" class="hidden">
      <td>
      <text id="redtext" class="red">hi</text>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="clonebtn">
  add row
</button>
```

Jquery

```
var original = $('#clone'); //get html for the sample row

$('#clonebtn').click(function() {
var clone = original.clone();
  clone.find('#clone').removeClass("hidden");
  clone.find('#redtext').removeClass("red");
  $('#cloneinhere > tbody:last').append(clone);
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: there is a jsfiddle link that shows html, jquery and css

Comment: Right, but the code isn't ***in your question***, it's somewhere else that may or may not be accessible along with your question one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below solution, will work out for you

```js
$(function() {
var original = $('#clone'); //get html for the sample row

$('#clonebtn').click(function() {
var clone = original.clone();
 clone.removeClass("hidden");
   clone.find('#redtext').removeClass("red");
  $('#cloneinhere > tbody:last').append(clone);
});
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cloneinhere">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="clone" class="hidden">
      <td>
      <text id="redtext" class="red">hi</text>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="clonebtn">
  add row
</button>
```

Comment: thank you, this worked. will accept when time allows